# vagrant share folder "npm install" is failed. "text file is busy, rename..."

Tags: npm, vagrant

I have windows 10 pro which is my host, and I am building the following vagrant machine in the windows:

```
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    # Enable symlinks in vagrant shared folder, https://coderwall.com/p/b5mu2w
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant-root", "1"]
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
  end
```

I am getting the following error when running npm install inside the machine:

`npm ERR! path /vagrant/hlf-http-api/node_modules/abbrev/package.json.610637167
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename '/vagrant/hlf-http-api/node_modules/abbrev/package.json.610637167' -> '/vagrant/hlf-http-api/node_modules/abbrev/package.json'`

when I run this command from windows it works perfect.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing this issue, even starting Vagrant as Admin didn't fix it, so it seems is not a issue of Symlink, since i was able to create symlink when open it as Admin

the issue seems to be probably extension length? not sure about that,

but the solution i've found is this one : https://kawadev.net/vagrant-npm-install-error/

TL;DR:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd
vagrant plugin update
```

and change

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./vue-develop", "/vue-develop"
   ↓
config.vm.synced_folder "./vue-develop", "/vue-develop", type: "nfs"
```

Reload the box

```
vagrant reload
```

To install use `--no-bin-links` anyways since i got error when i ran without admin

```
npm install --no-bin-links
```